# When is Crash data is sent from Mobile App to Crashlytics?

Tags: crashlytics, fabric.io, fabric-answers

Is the crash data sent to Crashlytics during the next successful launch or during the moment of crash ?

Comment: I think it will try to send the crash data right after app crash. If can't, it will try it when you open app next time. You can create a sample project and test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Crashes and non-fatal events are only sent when the app is relaunched post-crash.